# extract lines from file as an element perl

Tags: perl, extract

```
while (<IN>) {
  if (/<day>/../<\/day>/) {
    push (@temp, $_);
  }
}
```

hi, I want to push in to @temp array all the file lines between `<day>` and `</day>` as an element not line by line, because later on I will search after something in that element and if not equals I will exclude it. any ideea what to use in order to do so? thanks

Comment: This looks suspiciously like `XML` to me. Is it? If so, use a parser.

Comment: yes it is. ok, I will try. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (<IN>) {
  if (my $i = /<day>/../<\/day>/) {
    push @days, '' if $i == 1;
    $days[-1] .= $_;
  }
}
```